# MS Teams - Read all messages of a user

Tags: c#, api, chat, message, microsoft-teams

I am working on a project integration with MS teams when ever a message revived on my team account i need to process the message content. All document says its a protected API, is there any other way to read only messages of my own.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for reading the chat message of a user here is the API for [reading the chat messsage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) and if your concern is about listing the messages in a channel you ca go with this API for [List Channel Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http). To access these api you need to give the permission as mentioned in the document.